# Matrix Analysis textbook recommendation.

Tags: matrices, optimization, book-recommendation, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

After studying Linear Algebra Done Right and Wrong, I want to study more of matrix analysis like more decompositions, perturbation results, matrix computation, matrix calculus etc. What are some of books that one should read cover to cover to get started on these things or what portion of which books are must read. Thanks!

Comment: Golub and Van Loan's book is good, as is Trefethen and Bau's book.

Comment: Trefethen & Bau is a great book to work through cover to cover, doing as many exercises as you can.  It's relatively short.  Learn a matrix programming language too, if you haven't already (Matlab or Octave or Numpy).

Comment: It seems that you are talking about *numerical linear algebra* rather than *matrix analysis*. While the two areas certainly overlap (and not by a small amount), matrix analysis is more about using analytic methods to study matrix theory. It does not necessarily involve numerical aspects.

Comment: @NickAlger Should one read Golub cover to cover?

Comment: @icurays1 Thanks. I have that on my reading list already.

Comment: @user1551 I come from cs theory background and it seems the solid grasp of the topics I mentioned is very important. So if you have to recommend something based on their applied importance, what topics and references one should go through. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1131274 Sorry, I just wanted to clarify your question, not to discourage you. Anyway, as a deleted answer has pointed out, the widely recognised choices for numerical linear algebra and matrix analysis are Golub and van Loan's *Matrix Computations*, Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* and *Topics in Matrix Analysis* and Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis*. If you also want to study matrix functions, Higham's *Functions of Matrices: Theory and Computation"* is the de facto bible. It's hard to say which parts of the above books should be covered, as this depends very much on your own pace.

Comment: @user1131274 Cover to cover could be done, but seems a little extreme. It would probably be more useful if you read pieces here and there as needed, while doing your own experiments in Matlab/Octave. Like, when there is a specific topic that interests you, go to Golub's book and start reading the relevant section.